# What does “India-Pak. tensions: Have reasonably decent news from both countries, says Trump ” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Can someone please explain what the phrase above means? Here what does reasonably decent news mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is headline style where words that are understood from context are often dropped.

The headline means "Regarding the tensions between India and Pakistan, Trump says 'I have reasonably decent news from both countries'  ".

"Reasonably decent" is rather vague; here it means there are some indications that tensions may be easing *somewhat* or at least not getting worse.

Comment: Technically, it means "I haven't the foggiest idea what's going on, but my advisors don't seem terribly upset about things."

Comment: I thought the technical meaning was "It looks as though there's prime beachfront property available in both countries."

Comment: @TRomano so finally what does the above head line mean so Decent News Refers to Good news or Bad news or tensed News?? Here is the Link of the Full News https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/live-updates-india-pak-tensions-in-the-aftermath-of-balakot-air-strike-and-pulwama-attack/article26394724.ece?homepage=true

Comment: The reasonable inference to be drawn here from a phrase as vague as "reasonably decent" is that tensions may be easing or that they are not getting worse.  I don't need to read the full article as I am not commenting on the political situation itself.  I'm only explaining how you might reasonably interpret the phrase.